# Exotic automorphisms of the fundamental group of a curve?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, profinite-groups, anabelian-geometry

A while back, Jordan S. Ellenberg brought the following problem to my attention.

If $G$ is a residually finite group, let $\widehat G$ be its profinite completion.
Let $S$ be a closed surface of genus $g \geq 2$, and let $\pi$ be its topological fundamental group.
Let $\mathrm{Mod}(S)$ be the mapping class group of $S$.

There is homomorphism $\widehat{\mathrm{Mod}(S)} \to \mathrm{Out}(\widehat \pi)$.  Is this map surjective?

In other words, does the geometric fundamental group of the moduli space surject the outer automorphisms of the geometric fundamental group of the curve?

**Edit**:  As Jordan points out, the map is not surjective.  So, the question is:

What's the closure of the image of $\mathrm{Mod}(S)$ in $\mathrm{Out}(\widehat \pi)$?

Or, more precisely, for Henry:

As Jordan explains, there is a map $\mathrm{Out}(\widehat \pi) \to \mathrm{Sp}_{2g}(\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}) \to \widehat{\mathbb{Z}}^\star$

Is the closure of the image of $\mathrm{Mod}(S)$ in $\mathrm{Out}(\widehat \pi)$ the preimage of 1 and -1?

Comment: I assume that we're talking about continuous automorphisms of pi hat?

Comment: Yes. But I think it follows from Nikolov and Segal's theorem (that finite index subgroups of topologically finitely generated profinite groups are open) that every automorphism will be continuous.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, this question came to me (or someone else with my initials) via Mark Kisin, so I can't claim credit (and for all I know it came to him from elsewhere.)

Second:  there's one obvious obstruction to surjectivity.  Namely, the map

$$\widehat{\mathrm{Mod}(S)} \to \mathrm{Sp}_{2g}(\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}) -det \to \widehat{\mathbb{Z}}^\star$$

has image $\mathbb{Z}^\star$, which is to say $\pm1$.  On the other hand,

$$\mathrm{Out}(\widehat \pi) \to \mathrm{Sp}_{2g}(\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}) -det \to \widehat{\mathbb{Z}}^\star$$

is surjective.  So the map you ask about is definitely not surjective.  The question is whether in some sense "this is the only way the map fails to be surjective."  Since I don't have a precise meaning in mind for the phrase in quotes, one might just say "what is the closure of the image of the mapping class group in $\mathrm{Out}(\widehat \pi)$?"

By the way, is there a topological proof that $\mathrm{Out}(\widehat \pi) \to \widehat{\mathbb{Z}}^\star$ is surjective?  The only proof I know is that if you write down an algebraic curve $X$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, the images of Frobenii in $\mathrm{Out}(\pi_1^{et}(X_\overline{\mathbb{Q}}))$ give you automorphisms of pihat with lots of different determinants.  Other than this I don't know how to construct a single element of $\mathrm{Out}(\widehat \pi)$ whose determinant is not $\pm1$!

Comment: Oops.  I think you had already pointed this out to me.  I readjusted the question.

Comment: Surely the precise statement of the questions should be: "Is the closure of the image of Mod(S) equal to the preimage of {+-1} under the map you define Out(pihat) - > Zhat^*?" 

Comment: You're right, Henry, I've added the precise question now.

Answer (score 3):

Just a non-thought-out thought:

For any finite simple group $S$, consider the set of maps from $\pi$ to $S$ up to conjugacy. Now, $\mathrm{Out}(\widehat{\pi})$ acts on this set.  Now consider the composition of this action with the permutation character; you get a character $f(S)$ of $\mathrm{Out}(\widehat{\pi})$ valued in $\pm 1$. 
[If $S$ is $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$,  I think but didn't check that the corresponding character is the "determinant composed with the quadratic residue symbol mod $p$," if that makes sense.]

I have no idea as to the image of the map $F = \prod_{S} f(S)$, but it seems plausible to me that it is uncountable. On the other hand, since $\mathrm{Out}(\pi)$ is finitely generated, the restriction of $F$
to it must have finite image.  (Slight clarification: restrict the product over $S$ to nonabelian finite simple groups, since the abelian ones provide no new information.)