# Discretifications of the fundamental group functor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, anabelian-geometry, fundamental-group, reference-request

Grothendieck calls a "discretification" of a profinite group $\widehat G$, a
discrete group $G$ whose profinite completion is isomorphic to $\widehat G$.

Does Grothendieck also  define a notion of the "discretification"
of a functor to profinite groups, and particulary that of the
algebraic fundamental group functor?

The automorphisms of the geometric point act on the discretifications
of the fundamental group functor; and thus one can ask:

> are all discretifications of the the algebraic fundamental group *functor*
>   related by automorphisms of the geometric point? To simplify the question,
>   one may abelianise the functor and/or restrict it to a full subcategory of
>   schemes $X\longrightarrow S$, $S=\mathrm{Spec}\ k$ a number field or $k=K$.

Here is the same question with some more notation and detail.
Please excuse my poor notation: I am not very familiar with the language of schemes.

Say a functor $F$ to finitely generated Abelian groups is a *discretification*
of a functor $F'$ to profinite groups iff for every $X$, $F(X)$ is 
a discretification of $F'(X)$. Equivalently, one is given an equivalence $\widehat F \Rightarrow F'$
(where $\widehat F(X)=\widehat{F(X)}$ is the profinite completion of $F(X)$.)

The algebraic fundamental group is, or at least defines,
a functor $\pi_1^{alg}: \mathrm{Spec}\ K\text{\Schemes} \longrightarrow \text{ProfiniteGroups}$ from the category $\mathrm{Spec}\ K\text{\Schemes}= \mathrm{Mor} (\mathrm{Spec}\ K, \text{\Schemes})$ of Schemes cosliced over a geometric point $\mathrm{Spec}\ K$.

There is a canonical $\mathrm{Aut}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ action on $\mathrm{Spec}\ K\text{\Schemes}$ which extends to an action on the discretifications of this functor. Did Grothendicek conjecture anything about this action?

Is there a better way to state this question? E.g. using the fact that for K the field of algebraic numbers $\mathrm{Aut}(K/\mathbb{Q})=\pi_1^{alg}(\mathrm{Spec}\ \mathbb{Q}, \mathrm{Spec}\ K)$.

One can modify the question by replacing the category of  Schemes by a subcategory of Schemes over $\mathrm{Spec}\ k$ or some other scheme, and then considering double cosets of $\mathrm{Aut}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ and $\mathrm{Aut}(k/\mathbb{Q})$ action; as an example, one may consider the full subcategory of etale covers  of direct products of moduli spaces of curves....

Perhaps I should also add that probably I can prove some very partial positive results, for some very small and "abelian" subcategories of Schemes. That's the 
motivation for the question.

Comment: Possibly related question (or not - I'm out of my depth): http://mathoverflow.net/questions/4972/exotic-automorphisms-of-the-fundamental-group-of-a-curve .

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this kind of question is probably indirectly related...But I do not see a direct relation. 

Comment: Is it obvious whether there exists any discretification?

Comment: Will Savin: the topological fundamental group is intended to be an example. it works for K=C or K⊂C and an appropriate subcategory of Schemes. (Well, the topological fundamental group of a smooth projective complex algebraic variety is not necessarily residually finite, so you have to do something about that). In general, I do not know; perhaps my definition is too naive to work for general Schemes. Also, in char p, I do not know; but possibly it is not too hard to construct by hand. 

Comment: I see. I thought it wouldn't work for $K\subset \mathbb C$ because of the classic example that shows the fundamental group of a complex manifold is not determined by its algebraic structure, but that is just an example of the $Aut(\mathbb C/\mathbb Q)$ action on discretization. In characteristic $p$, The Artin-Schreier sequence shows that $H^1(X,\mathbb Z/p)= Mor(\pi_1(X),\mathbb Z/p)$ is infinite-dimensional for a general scheme, so $\pi_1(x)$ is infinitely generated, which doesn't rule out a by-hand construction but makes it seem difficult.

Comment: Will Savin: yes, it is exactly the point of the question to "go around" that counterexample. I should perhaps add that the reason for the question is that one can prove very partial positive results, for some very small subcategories of Schemes.